# Axios - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have written code for adding new articles but the Axios post request is not going through, the error I am getting is : 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 
(Internal Server Error)
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)

I have compared it with a similar project to compare which looks fine.

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Articles = new Schema({
    title: {
        type:String
    },
    content: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
        type:String
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Articles', Articles);
```

Database model

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = 4000;
const routes = express.Router();
const Articles = require('./db');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dummies", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

connection.on("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to the database");
});

routes.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    Articles.find((err, articles) => {
        if (!err) { res.json(articles);}       
    }
    )
})

routes.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    let article = new Articles(req.body);
    article.save().then(() => {
        res.status(200).json({ "article": "article saved" })
    });
})

app.use('/dummies', routes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Listening...')
})
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class AddArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title:"",
            content:"",
            author:""
        };

        this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
        this.onChangeContent = this.onChangeContent.bind(this);
        this.onChangeAuthor = this.onChangeAuthor.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeTitle = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            title:event.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeContent = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            content:event.target.value
        })
    }

    onChangeAuthor = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            author:event.target.value
        })
    }

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        let article = {
            title: this.state.title,
            content: this.state.content,
            author: this.state.author
        }

        axios.post("http://localhost:4000/dummies/add", article).then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Navbar />
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeTitle} value={this.state.title}/>
                        <input type="textarea" onChange={this.onChangeContent} value={this.state.content} />
                        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeAuthor} value={this.state.author}/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Article"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default AddArticle;
```

AddArticle.js

Comment: the issue is going to be on the server side.

Comment: Update your question again, we don't see `AddArticle.js` content. Add `catch` block for your `article.save()` method to see what happen in server side.

Comment: Try sending the same request using Postman and use debug, to me it looks like an issue with your routing.

Comment: I saw similar errors when deploying my app to Heroku. Ultimately, the reason was obvious: One of the API servers axios was attempting to connect to had a problem (the remote db was empty). All this revealed one thing: I have to build-in graceful fallback when an API server is unavailable, so that things don't crash hard.

Comment: i'm not sure  but tyr this may works. routes.post("/add", async (req, res) => {
    let article = new Articles(req.body);
    await article.save(); return res.status(200).send({message : "saved"})
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the same request method on both client and server side
(e.g post-post or get-get), I face same issue with same error when the method was not same in both side, else the below error will raise

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500 at createError
```